# Integrate with a 3rd party website

Tags: managed-package, authentication, iframe, canvas, 2gp

We currently have a 2GP Managed Package that contains an LWC component that is basically a UI in Salesforce for our API, and that we want to distribute across external orgs. We use Apex Callouts + Protected Custom Settings (with API Keys) to perform the API calls. Our goals are:

1. Be able to have a bidirectional connection between Salesforce and our system (as opposed to the Apex callouts, where we can only perform calls from Salesforce).
2. (Bonus) Be able to frame a 3rd party website, perform some actions there and reconcile the system status with SF's status. This will only used in some actions, others will directly call the API without going through Canva.

For example, the user clicks a button in our LWC component, a modal opens where a website is framed, they can create an object in that system that has a counterparty in Salesforce, and the data of the new object is pushed back to SF. From that onwards, we are also able to push any modification of the object in the system back to SF.

I've been reading the docs, but no method looks to fit perfectly this use case. Also, I'm especially concerned about the unknown unknowns around packaging the different components. My thoughts:

**Requirement #1: Having a bi-directional connection**

Here, [OAuth 2.0 + Connected App seems to be the way to go](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5). After doing the OAuth flow, the system has the tokens required to push back the data to SF. However:

- Is there an easy way to also use it to authenticate the API calls (e.g. add by default a signature to the calls based on the OAuth secrets that we can later verify)? I understand that we would still need the API keys to do a call SF -> 3rd party API.
- How much intervention would be required by the users to set up the Connected App?

On the other hand, I've seen that there is something called External Client Apps, advertised as "*a new generation of connected apps*". Seems to be yet another case where SF decides to implement something new to supersede another feature, and then the old one doesn't support the new things, but the new one is half-implemented. Checking the [feature comparison](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.connected_apps_and_external_client_apps_features.htm&type=5) I see that Connected Apps need a tweak to be included in a 2GP, while the External Client App lack support of OAuth 2.0 and Canvas.

**Frame a 3rd party website**

***Canvas***

Although it seems to fit the requirements, it seems to be a technology that is not maintained by Salesforce anymore:

- The [last important update for its SDK](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceCanvasFrameworkSDK/commits/master/) was 7 years ago
- It is not natively supported on the newest SF features:

  - Not supported directly in LWC, only in Aura
  - Not supported in the External Client Apps, only in the Connected Apps

Also, if you have experience with them, I'd love to understand better the challenges you've faced, especially on the authentication/packaging side, and how its authentication interacts with the previous point (it seems if we are using OAuth + Connected App it can be reused).

***Iframe***

Just framing the site on the LWC, and then, given that we have the bi-directional connection, write back to SF.

***Web tabs***

We want to open certain parts of our website on certain actions, not to have our website framed all the time.

I feel these are fairly standard use cases (especially #1). What approach have you followed and which advice do you have? Thanks!